# Would foreign stocks held in a US brokerage account by a nonresident alien be subject to US estate taxes?

Tags: united-states, stocks, non-resident, international, estate-planning

Suppose a non-resident alien investor has a US brokerage account at a US stock brokerage firm that has access to many foreign stock markets. The investor uses the US brokerage account to buy shares of non-US companies listed on foreign stock exchanges (e.g. Tokyo Stock Exchange, London Stock Exchange). Would the foreign shares be subject to US estate taxes?

Would the answer be different if the investor has a US brokerage account that only allows the buying of foreign shares through OTC ["F Shares"/"Ordinary Shares"](https://www.otcmarkets.com/files/FAQ-on-Ordinary-Shares.pdf)? Would F shares held by the investor be subject to US estate taxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The account itself matters less than the investment, the exchange on which the security is sold doesn't matter at all. For each investment/asset in the account (including available cash), a [situs would need to be determined](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i706na#en_US_202208_publink100075478). If the situs is in the US - then it would be included in the taxable estate.

The situs is determined as of the time of death, not the time of purchase (e.g.: a share of a corporation that was organized in the UK when purchased, but then was reorganized in the US later - would be included in the gross estate).

Comment: The IRS webpage says "Generally, no matter where stock certificates are physically located, stock of corporations organized in or under U.S. law is property located in the United States, and all other corporate stock is property located outside the United States." Does this mean that US-listed ADR shares are subject to estate taxes since ADR shares are organized under US law?

Comment: @Flux yes, probably. I'd contact a specialist on asset situs determination, though.

Comment: The answers to [Are non-US funds held at US brokerages by non-resident non-citizens liable for Estate Tax?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/148766/are-non-us-funds-held-at-us-brokerages-by-non-resident-non-citizens-liable-for-e) and [Are ADRs of US stocks purchased on non-US exchanges subject to US Estate Tax if held by non-resident non-nationals?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/148765/are-adrs-of-us-stocks-purchased-on-non-us-exchanges-subject-to-us-estate-tax-if) seem to imply that US-listed ADRs are not subject to US estate tax for non-resident aliens.

Comment: @Flux the relevant portion refers to a PLR, which is not an authority. You'll need to present your own facts and circumstances to get a PLR speicifc to your situation. That said - as I've suggested before and will suggest again: if this is an actual issue you're dealing with, you should hire a professional. If you're just trying to satisfy your curiosity - then you've got what you asked for, stop trolling.